# Display more specific items from a Json file

Tags: javascript, json

Already solved.

I have a Json array called cars. There is the value "type" inside, which indicates required fuel.
For clarify, I have created an example page where you can try it: https://jsfiddle.net/vladoss/dp22yshy/

Current solution works for selected options "all", "diesel", "petrol" and "gas". I need adjust it to make functional also combinated selections - gas + petrol, gas + diesel, diesel + petrol.

```js
//json - list of cars
var cars = [
    { title: 'Diesel', type: 'diesel', url: '', img: ''},
    { title: 'Petrol', type: 'petrol', url: '', img: ''},
    { title: 'Gas',    type: 'gas',    url: '', img: ''},
];

//script
window.addEventListener('load', function() {    
    var results = document.getElementById('cars');
    
    function show() {
        var typeField = document.getElementById('type');  //read selected type
        var s = typeField.selectedIndex;                 //index of the selected type
        var type = typeField.options[s].value;      //value of the var s
        var resultsHtml = '';
        
        var carsLength = cars.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < carsLength; i++) {
            //functional for the select "all" and "individual" types
   //I need add a possibility for selecting combination of two and more types (diesel + petrol)
            if (type == 'all' || type == cars[i].type) {
                resultsHtml += '<a href="' + cars[i].url +'">\
         <div class="rollover"><img class="lazy playable" src="' + cars[i].img + '" alt="'+          cars[i].title +'" width="60px" height="50px"></div></a>'
            }
        }
        
        results.innerHTML = resultsHtml;
    } 
    var showBtn = document.getElementById('showBtn'); 
    showBtn.addEventListener('click', show);
});
```

```html
 <label>fuel</label>
     <select id="type">
        <option value="all">All</option> 
        <option value="petrol">petrol</option>
        <option value="diesel">diesel</option>  
         
         <!-- I need make functional these three options below -->
        <option value="diesel" + value="petrol">diesel and petrol</option>  
        <option value="diesel" + value="gas">diesel and gas</option>  
        <option value="petrol" + value="gas">petrol and gas</option>  
    </select>
 <button id="showBtn">Show</button>
 <div id="cars"></div>
```

Thanks for every help! :).
https://jsfiddle.net/vladoss/dp22yshy/

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/dp22yshy/1/

Comment: yeah, exactly! Thank you very much :).

Comment: This isn't JSON, `cars` is just plain javascript. JSON doesn't allow things like `var cars = ` and unquoted property keys like `title:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `-` separated value, split that on change, then check for `indexOf` in the selected values array:

```
<!--Split by - --->
<option value="diesel-petrol">diesel and petrol</option>  
<option value="diesel-gas">diesel and gas</option>  
<option value="petrol-gas">petrol and gas</option>
```

JS:

```
 function show() {
    var typeField = document.getElementById('type');    //read selected type
    var s = typeField.selectedIndex;                    //index of the selected type
    var type = typeField.options[s].value.split("-");   //value of the var s - array format
    var resultsHtml = '';

    var carsLength = cars.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < carsLength; i++) {
        //functional for the select "all" and "individual" types
        //I need add a possibility for selecting combination of two and more types (diesel + petrol)
        if (type == 'all' || type.indexOf(cars[i].type) > -1) {
            resultsHtml += '<a href="' + cars[i].url +'">\
                            <div class="rollover"><img class="lazy playable" src="' + cars[i].img + '" alt="'+                                  cars[i].title +'" width="60px" height="50px"></div></a>'
        }
    }

    results.innerHTML = resultsHtml;
}
```

Demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/dp22yshy/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
//json - list of cars
var cars = [{
  title: 'Diesel',
  type: 'diesel',
  url: '',
  img: ''
}, {
  title: 'Petrol',
  type: 'petrol',
  url: '',
  img: ''
}, {
  title: 'Gas',
  type: 'gas',
  url: '',
  img: ''
}, {
  title: 'Diesel and Petrol',
  type: 'diesel_petrol',
  url: '',
  img: ''
}, {
  title: 'Diesel and Gas',
  type: 'diesel_gas',
  url: '',
  img: ''
}, {
  title: 'Petrol and Gas',
  type: 'petrol_gas',
  url: '',
  img: ''
}];

//script
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var results = document.getElementById('cars');

  function show() {
    var typeField = document.getElementById('type'); //read selected type
    var s = typeField.selectedIndex; //index of the selected type
    var type = typeField.options[s].value; //value of the var s
    var resultsHtml = '';

    var carsLength = cars.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < carsLength; i++) {
      //functional for the select "all" and "individual" types
      //I need add a possibility for selecting combination of two and more types (diesel + petrol)
      if (type == 'all' || type == cars[i].type) {
        resultsHtml += '<a href="' + cars[i].url + '">\
         <div class="rollover"><img class="lazy playable" src="' + cars[i].img + '" alt="' + cars[i].title + '" width="60px" height="50px"></div></a>'
      }
    }

    results.innerHTML = resultsHtml;
  }
  var showBtn = document.getElementById('showBtn');
  showBtn.addEventListener('click', show);
});
```

```html
<label>fuel</label>
<select id="type">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="petrol">petrol</option>
  <option value="diesel">diesel</option>

  <!-- I need make functional these three options below -->
  <option value="diesel_petrol" + value="petrol">diesel and petrol</option>
  <option value="diesel_gas" + value="gas">diesel and gas</option>
  <option value="petrol_gas" + value="gas">petrol and gas</option>
</select>
<button id="showBtn">Show</button>
<div id="cars"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I meant what tymeJV added. Anyway, the problem is solved. :)